# Appending multiple lists containing numpy array in Python

Tags: python, list, numpy

I want to append multiple lists containing a numpy array. I try with `append` but it doesn't append the two lists for different `t`. I present the current and expected outputs.

```
import numpy as np
N=2
arsigma=[]
for t in range(0,2):
    sigma=0.02109*t*np.ones((2*N*(N+1), 1))
    arsigma.append(sigma)
    arsigma=list(sigma)
    print("sigma =",[sigma])
```

The current output is

```
sigma = [array([[0.],
       [0.],
       [0.],
       [0.],
       [0.],
       [0.],
       [0.],
       [0.],
       [0.],
       [0.],
       [0.],
       [0.]])]
sigma = [array([[0.02109],
       [0.02109],
       [0.02109],
       [0.02109],
       [0.02109],
       [0.02109],
       [0.02109],
       [0.02109],
       [0.02109],
       [0.02109],
       [0.02109],
       [0.02109]])]
```

The expected output is

```
sigma=[array([[0.],
           [0.],
           [0.],
           [0.],
           [0.],
           [0.],
           [0.],
           [0.],
           [0.],
           [0.],
           [0.],
           [0.]]), array([[0.02109],
           [0.02109],
           [0.02109],
           [0.02109],
           [0.02109],
           [0.02109],
           [0.02109],
           [0.02109],
           [0.02109],
           [0.02109],
           [0.02109],
           [0.02109]])]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list comprehension instead:

```
N = 2
arsigma = [0.02109*t*np.ones((2*N*(N+1), 1)) for t in range(2)]
```